# Twitter Connect callback url

Tags: php, javascript, twitter, twitter-anywhere

I am using the Twitter connect button with @anywhere to use the Twitter features of my app. I set the callback url but when you click "connect with Twitter" and connect it, it says its connected. Shouldn't the callback url direct it to the profile page where I specified it? If not, how do I change it so you hit connect, then you are brought to the callback page. Note this is not OAuth, just connect with Twitter found
[right here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome#login-signup)

I don't think it can be an `<a href="foo"></a>`
Thank you in advance!